# Animating react-native-svg dash length of a <Circle />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, svg, react-native

Hey everyone I'm trying to achieve effect similar to: https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js
(circle one)

I was able to successfully animate some svg elements before using `setNativeProps` approach, but it is failing for me this time with dash length, below is a gif demonstrating current behaviour (circle is change from full to semi full when it receives new props):

[image]

Essentially I am trying to animate this change instead of it just flicking in, below is full source for this rectangular progress bar, basic idea is that is uses `Circle` and `strokeDasharray` in order to show circular progress, it receives `currentExp` and `nextExp` as values for characters experience in order to calculate percentage left before they reach next lvl.

Component uses pretty standard set of elements, besides few dimension / animation and colour props from stylesheed and `styled-components` library for styling.

**NOTE:** project is importing this library from [expo.io](https://expo.io) but it's essentially `react-native-svg`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Animated } from "react-native";
import { Svg } from "expo";
import { colour, dimension, animation } from "../Styles";

const { Circle, Defs, LinearGradient, Stop } = Svg;

const SSvg = styled(Svg)`
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: ${dimension.ExperienceCircleMarginLeft};
  margin-top: ${dimension.ExperienceCircleMarginTop};
`;

class ExperienceCircle extends Component {
  // -- prop validation ----------------------------------------------------- //
  static propTypes = {
    nextExp: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    currentExp: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };

  // -- state --------------------------------------------------------------- //
  state = {
    percentage: new Animated.Value(0)
  };

  // -- methods ------------------------------------------------------------- //
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.percentage.addListener(percentage => {
      const circumference = dimension.ExperienceCircleRadius * 2 * Math.PI;
      const dashLength = percentage.value * circumference;
      this.circle.setNativeProps({
        strokeDasharray: [dashLength, circumference]
      });
    });
    this._onAnimateExp(this.props.nextExp, this.props.currentExp);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ nextExp, currentExp }) {
    this._onAnimateExp(currentExp, nextExp);
  }

  _onAnimateExp = (currentExp, nextExp) => {
    const percentage = currentExp / nextExp;
    Animated.timing(this.state.percentage, {
      toValue: percentage,
      duration: animation.duration.long,
      easing: animation.easeOut
    }).start();
  };

  // -- render -------------------------------------------------------------- //
  render() {
    const { ...props } = this.props;
    // const circumference = dimension.ExperienceCircleRadius * 2 * Math.PI;
    // const dashLength = this.state.percentage * circumference;
    return (
      <SSvg
        width={dimension.ExperienceCircleWidthHeight}
        height={dimension.ExperienceCircleWidthHeight}
        {...props}
      >
        <Defs>
          <LinearGradient
            id="ExperienceCircle-gradient"
            x1="0"
            y1="0"
            x2="0"
            y2={dimension.ExperienceCircleWidthHeight * 2}
          >
            <Stop
              offset="0"
              stopColor={`rgb(${colour.lightGreen})`}
              stopOpacity="1"
            />
            <Stop
              offset="0.5"
              stopColor={`rgb(${colour.green})`}
              stopOpacity="1"
            />
          </LinearGradient>
        </Defs>
        <Circle
          ref={x => (this.circle = x)}
          cx={dimension.ExperienceCircleWidthHeight / 2}
          cy={dimension.ExperienceCircleWidthHeight / 2}
          r={dimension.ExperienceCircleRadius}
          stroke="url(#ExperienceCircle-gradient)"
          strokeWidth={dimension.ExperienceCircleThickness}
          fill="transparent"
          strokeDasharray={[0, 0]}
          strokeLinecap="round"
        />
      </SSvg>
    );
  }
}

export default ExperienceCircle;
```

**UPDATE:** Extended discussion and more examples (similar approach working for different elements) available via issue posted to `react-native-svg` repo: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/451

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is actually quite simple when you know how SVG inputs work, one of the problems with react-native-SVG (or SVG inputs, in general, is that it doesn't work with angle), so when you want to work on a circle you need to transform angle to the inputs which it takes, this can be done, by simply writing a function such as (you necessarily don't need to memorize or totally understand how transformation works, this is the standard):

[image: result]

```
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
        var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

        return {
            x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
            y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
        };
    }
```

Then you add another function which can give you the d props in the right format:

```
function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

        var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
        var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

        var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

        var d = [
            "M", start.x, start.y,
            "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
        ].join(" ");

        return d;
    }
```

Now it is great, you have the function (describeArc) which gives you the perfect  parameter you need to describe your path (an arc of a circle):
so you can define the `PATH` as:

```
<AnimatedPath d={_d} stroke="red" strokeWidth={5} fill="none"/>
```

for example, if you need an arc of a circle of radius `R` between 45 degrees to 90 degrees, simply define `_d` as:

```
_d = describeArc(R, R, R, 45, 90);
```

now that we know everything about how SVG PATH works, we can implement react native animation, and define an animated state such as `progress`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Animated, Easing} from 'react-native';
import Svg, {Circle, Path} from 'react-native-svg';

AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            progress: new Animated.Value(0),
        }
    }
componentDidMount(){
        Animated.timing(this.state.progress,{
            toValue:1,
            duration:1000,

        }).start()
}



    render() {
        function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
            var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

            return {
                x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
            };
        }

        function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

            var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
            var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

            var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

            var d = [
                "M", start.x, start.y,
                "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
            ].join(" ");

            return d;
        }

        let R = 160;
        let dRange = [];
        let iRange = [];
        let steps = 359;
        for (var i = 0; i<steps; i++){
            dRange.push(describeArc(160, 160, 160, 0, i));
            iRange.push(i/(steps-1));
        }


        var _d = this.state.progress.interpolate({
            inputRange: iRange,
            outputRange: dRange
        })

        return (
            <Svg style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Circle
                    cx={R}
                    cy={R}
                    r={R}
                    stroke="green"
                    strokeWidth="2.5"
                    fill="green"
                />
                {/*       X0  Y0               X1   Y1*/}
                <AnimatedPath d={_d}
                      stroke="red" strokeWidth={5} fill="none"/>

            </Svg>
        );
    }
    }

    export default App;
```

This simple component will work as you want

- At the top of the componet, we write,

`AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);`

because `Path` which is imported from react-native-svg is not native react-native component and we turn it to animated by this.

- at `constructor` we defined progress as the animated state which should change during animation.
- at `componentDidMount` the animation process is started.
- at the beginning of `render` method, the two functions needed to define SVG `d` parameters are declared (`polarToCartesian` and `describeArc`).
- then react-native `interpolate` is used on `this.state.progress` to interpolate the change in `this.state.progress` from 0 to 1, into change in d parameter. However, there are two points here that you should bear in mind:

  1- the change between two arcs with different lengths is not linear, so linear interpolation from angle 0 to 360 does not work as you would like, as a result, it is better to define the animation in different steps of n degrees (i used 1 degrees, u can increase or decrease it if needed.).

  2- arc cannot continue up to 360 degrees (because it is equivalent to 0), so it is better to finish animation at a degree close to but not equal to 360 (such as 359.9)
- at the end of the return section, the UI is described.

Comment: Here is a snack for this https://snack.expo.io/B1qSWJfvG
Any suggestions for making the animated path appear to be 360%?

Comment: This answers makes sense. I was also able to use the approached used in the question very smoothly. It's implementation is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't tied to the svg library, I think you could checkout this library: https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress, it might be a much simpler way to achieve what your looking for.

Comment: Afraid I am, but this link looks promising, I'll see if I can figure out how to port it over to `react-native-svg`

Comment: Do you need to port it or wouldn't that library work as is? Just wondering

Comment: Issue here is me trying to stick with expo.io without ejecting, this means I can't use non expo native libs, which is fine, well up to this point. I'm certain this is achievable with react-native-svg lib that comes with expo, but just haven't figured it out.

Comment: I see that makes sense. Best of luck!

Comment: this library is buggy. The circle is cropped for both (iOS and Android).

Answer (score 1):

Another absolute great library for animating svg's is https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/ 
This is **standalone** without dependencies and easy to use.

Maybe this fits your needs?

Comment: This library is not for react-native I think, however an awesome stuff, thanks.